# how to retrieve records of parent table in many to many relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `User` model and `Job` model. There is many to many relation between them. Pivot table name is `job_user`. Now I have three foreign keys columns in pivot table; two from user table and one from job table. Now my question is how I query so I will able to show all records of table user and table job based on foreign keys columns of pivot table in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

**All jobs of a specific user**

```
$user = User::find(1);
$jobs = $user->jobs;
```

**All users of a specific job**

```
$job = Job::find(1);
$users = $job->users;
```

**Show columns**

```
$user = User::find(1);
$jobs = $user->jobs;

for ($jobs as $job) {
  echo $job->id;
}
```

**Retrieving intermediate table columns**

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach ($user->jobs as $job) {
    echo $job->pivot->created_at;
}
```

Check the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) for more details.

---

**PASSING DATA TO VIEW**

Your controller:

```
$users = User::all();
return View::make('yourView', ['users' => $users]);
```

Your view:

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)   
   @foreach ($user->jobs as $job)   
     {{ $job->id }}
   @endforeach                
 @endforeach
```

Comment: @waleed you not specified in the question.

Comment: i mentioned that how to show all records of table user and job based on foreign keys columns of job_ user in other words i only want to show  all the records of table user and job whose id is saved as a foreign keys in pivot table

Comment: thanks for ur answer, Now what if from table user two ids one is trainerid and other is student id and from job table job id is moving as foreign key in pivot table.  now i want to show all students and job assigned to trainer

Comment: @waleed you're changing the original question. Create a new question and describe your real problem.